# How to implement CAS (Central Authentication Service) using CPP REST SDK?

Tags: c++, rest, postman, cas, cpprest-sdk

Can anybody provide some tutorial or example on CAS authentication implemented in CPP REST SDK of Microsoft in C++?

Is it possible to test CAS based API in POSTMAN?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

you can find examples on the [document](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html)